# How to split a string by x amount of characters

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a program where a user enters a list of numbers in the form of a string. This list of numbers is always a multiple of 8.

So the list can contain 8, 16, 32, 40, 48, etc. numbers.

I need to split that string into every 8 characters.

For example, say the user entered "1234123445674567"

How can I split it into a string array where (0) is "12341234" and (1) is "45674567"

**Note:** The size of the array has to be equal to the length of the string divided by 8.

Like this:

```
Dim stringArray(txtInput.Text.Length/8) as String
```

Edit: I know I could do this by making a loop that counts 8 numbers and splits it into an array but that would be lengthy and take a few variables and I know there's a more efficient way to do it. I just don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should split the string into an array of 8-character substrings

```
Dim orig = "12344321678900987"
Dim res = Enumerable.Range(0,orig.Length\8).[Select](Function(i) orig.Substring(i*8,8))
```

Comment: By the way, VB is smart enough not to need `[Select]`.

Comment: @minitech I have no idea of the VB syntax - I translated this query automatically from C# :)

Comment: Yeah, nobody wants to write VB anymore :) Keywords in VB following a `.` don't need to be escaped with `[]` is all. So you could make it a little neater with `.Select` instead.

Comment: Note: Your string length must be divisible by the substring length for this solution to work. Otherwise, it will drop the last substring.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a `For` loop and `Substring`:

```
Dim strings As New List(Of String)

For i As Integer = 0 To Me.txtInput.Text.Length - 1 Step 8
    strings.Add(Me.txtInput.Text.Substring(i, 8))
Next
```

To convert the `strings` list to an array (if you really need one) you can use `strings.ToArray()`.

---

Also, you could use regular expressions and LINQ for a fancy one-liner:

```
Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(Me.txtInput.Text, ".{8}").Select(Function(x) x.Value)
```

Comment: I like your answer more than the other guys. Especially the one-liner seems very efficient. Are there any extra things I have to add or import into my program to make it work? I'm going to test it and if it works I'll accept your answer

Comment: @MarkKramer: No, there shouldn't be. The one-liner needs LINQ, which is only available in .NET 3.5 and up (VB 2008 or higher) but the first one works in practically everything.

Comment: Is LINQ something the user needs installed on their computer? Or just something I need on mine that comes with Visual Studio to compile the code

Comment: @MarkKramer: It comes with .NET 3.5, so if you can use it in your application at compile-time you can use it on anybody else's computer that your code would normally run on, yes.

Comment: Okay. Also, I've got another question for you. I made my program using Visual Studio 2010 pro. Does my program require the .Net Framework 4.0 to work?

Comment: @MarkKramer: Most likely. You can change it, though, in My Project > Compile > Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the accepted answer, this will split a string into parts even if the string isn't divisible by the divisor

```
    Public Function SplitInParts(s As String, partLength As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("String cannot be null or empty.")
        End If
        If partLength <= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Split length has to be positive.")
        End If
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Ceiling(s.Length / partLength)).Select(Function(i) s.Substring(i * partLength, If(s.Length - (i * partLength) >= partLength, partLength, Math.Abs(s.Length - (i * partLength)))))
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function slice(ByVal s as String) As String()
    Return (From c As String in s).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a solution to the question. Where's the length of the slice passed in?